# Updating a field in an attribute table with values from a dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, field, esri

I am very new to python and have been trying for days to work write a function that decodes a field in my attribute table and adds the corresponding value (from the dictionary below) into the blank field. So for example when 'e1' shows up in my attribute table look up 'e' in the dictionary, find the corresponding value and print 'estu' into a blank field and then look up '1' and print 'arable' into the next blank field. (Blank fields have already been added to the attribute table). Below are is my dictionary and an image of the attribute table I am trying to decode and add updated values too.

**Dictionary Values**

```
valuedict = {
'e':'Estu',
'i':'Ice',
'l':'Lake',
'q':'Quarry',
'r':'River',
't':'Town',
'Class':{'1':'Arable',
'2':'Non Arable',
'3':'Protected'}}
```

**Values in my attribute table which need to be decoded**

[image: Image of values that require decoding]

Thank you in advance for any help on this - I am new to python and have spent a couple of days trying to do this with no luck!!

Answer (score 1):

i hope the following logic can help you solve your problem, but it's not a generic solution.. Lets say you read all the key column rows in keys list

```
    for key in keys:
        for letter in key:
            if letter in valuedict.keys():
                #next_field_value=valuedict[letter]
            elif letter in dict['class']:
                #next_field_value = valuedict['class'][letter]
```

I am sorry in case if you are looking for a generic solution.

Hope it Helps.
Thank you